# Why does __init__ of Exception require positional (not keyword) arguments in order to stringify exception correctly?

Tags: python

Can someone clarify the role of `super().__init__(a, b, c)` in making the second assertion pass? It will fail without it (empty string is returned from `str`).

Per my understanding `Exception` is a built-in type that takes no keyword arguments.
But what exactly is happening in `Exception` when the `super().__init__(a, b, c)` is called?
Can calling `init` like that have some unwanted side-effects?

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(a, b, c)

e1 = MyException('a', 'b', 'c')
assert str(e1) == "('a', 'b', 'c')"

e2 = MyException(a='a', b='b', c='c') 
assert str(e2) == "('a', 'b', 'c')" # if "super()..." part above is commented out, this assertion will not pass, because str(e2) is an empty string
```

Comment: If you don't call the superclass constructor, how will it initialize the internal data that it needs to generate the error string?

Comment: @Barmar: True.  But how do you know for sure that internal data is initialized in Exception  constructor? I mean we can assume it from behavior, but in order to make sure (and see what else is happening), I need to look at C source code for Exception, correct?

Comment: It doesn't, unless you need to make the clunky assertion pass. I wouldn't bother passing the arguments to `super().__init__()`, and instead test if `itemgetter('a', 'b', 'c')(e1) == ('a', 'b', 'c')`.

Comment: Or, pass the arguments, and check that `e1.args == ('a', 'b', 'c')`.

Comment: @chepner: That `itemgetter` code raises `TypeError: 'MyException' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `attrgetter`. (I use `itemgetter` much more often, so that's what my fingers typed.)

Comment: Also, the `args` check fails with keyword arguments and no `super().__init__` call.

Comment: The general rule is that a subclass should always call the superclass constructor, unless for some reason it needs to override its normal initialization.

Comment: @Barmar: Why does the first assertion pass even when `super` is commented out?

Comment: I don't know. I would expect the error to happen when calling `super().__init__()`, not when calling `str()`. Please add the traceback to the question.

Comment: @Barmar: there is no error on second assertion (other than Assertion Error). The assertion does not pass because the result of `str(e2)` is an empty string (when `super` part is commented out).

Comment: @Barmar constructor != initializer.  This code _does_ call the superclass constructor, because the code didn't override `__new__` to do otherwise.

Comment: @wim True, but for the purpose here the distinction is slight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `BaseException.__str__`, which you inherit if you don't otherwise define a `__str__` method, only considers the "args" tuple [(src)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Objects/exceptions.c#L119-L130). If you pass through as keyword arguments then the "args" will be empty.

Note: it is not necessary to call `super().__init__` for custom exception types, unless you need your type to work in cooperative multiple inheritance.

That's because the exception args attribute, which `BaseException.__str__` uses to render the error as a string, [is set by the `__new__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Objects/exceptions.c#L55-L61).

Comment: And if I wanted my custom exception to stringify correctly when both positional (first assertion in my question) and keyword (second) args are passed in, is calling `super().__init__` like in my question the way to go?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The way to go is to define your `__str__` method explicitly. If you're just implementing simple custom error types, not expected to be mixed in with others, then the `super()` proxy will resolve on `Exception -> BaseException -> object`, and none of their inits do anything interesting, so no need to use super at all imo.

Comment: @wim OTOH, unless the behavior of the superclasses' initializers are documented, you should call it because you don't know that it's safe to skip it. It may be needed to ensure Liskov substitutability.

Comment: @Barmar They don't normally do this in stdlib, for example [`subprocess.CalledProcessError`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/subprocess.py#L126-L137), [`argparse.ArgumentError`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/argparse.py#L754-L763). Realistically I don't think LSP is a genuine concern here.